# Ckan API, List more information on rest dataset

Tags: rest, api, ckan

I am using ckan 2.6.0

According with the documentation: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/legacy-api.html

I am trying to use the endpoint `/rest/dataset` and works (only for public data but works), it only returns an array of datasets names, and nothing else, an example can be found here http://demo.ckan.org/api/1/rest/dataset

Is there a way to get a complete listing for datasets ? I also tried the search endpoint and returns the same array.

For example I would like to get the title, description, tags, file types, etc, like in the image below:

[image: Dataset-List-Demo]

Answer (score 2):

The REST api is deprecated/unmaintained and has been for a long time. Follow the up-to-date API documentation [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/).

Answer (score 1):

package_search is your best bet: http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/package_search

That gives you a batch of datasets. Get more by paging through using the 'start' and 'rows' parameters.

If you simply want them all, then it's much better still to use a bulk download that some sites offer, such as data.gov.uk, which supplies it complete as a simple JSONL download: [Meta-data for data.gov.uk datasets](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/data_gov_uk-datasets).